# Listbox/text entry affecting grid layout tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, grid-layout

I'm making a setlist creator that will basically allow someone to copy a title from the library into a setlist. When I put everything in the grid, for some reason the text area and listbox are bumping the buttons and entry box oddly even though I've checked the rows and columns to make sure they're not overlapping. Should I be using frames or something? If this has to do with frames, how would I do that?

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.SetList_Label = Label(self, text = "Set List")
        self.SetList_Label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = W)

        self.SetList_Box = Text(width = 15, height = 10)
        self.SetList_Box.grid(row = 1, column = 0, rowspan = 9, columnspan = 4, padx = 5, sticky = W)

        self.empty = Label(self, text = "                                            ")
        self.empty.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 4)

        self.Library_Label = Label(self, text = "Library")
        self.Library_Label.grid(row = 0, column = 5, padx = 5, sticky = W)

        self.Library_List = Listbox(self)
        self.Library_List.insert(1, "Dooley")
        self.Library_List.insert(2, "Icky Wicky")
        self.Library_List.insert(3, "Pig in a Pen")
        self.Library_List.insert(4, "In the Highways")
        self.Library_List.insert(5, "Bile 'Em Cabbage")
        self.Library_List.insert(6, "I'll Fly Away")
        self.Library_List.grid(row = 1, column = 5, sticky = W)

        self.addto_setlist = Button(self, text = "Add To Setlist", command = self.get_title)
        self.addto_setlist.grid(row = 12, column = 0, padx = 5, sticky = W)

        self.addto_library = Button(self, text = "Add To Library", command = self.add_item)
        self.addto_library.grid(row = 12, column = 6, sticky = W)

        self.addtitle_box = Entry()
        self.addtitle_box.grid(row = 12, column = 5, sticky = W)

        self.delete_button = Button(self, text = "Delete Title", command = self.delete_item)
        self.delete_button.grid(row = 12, column = 7, padx = 5, sticky = W)

    def add_item(self):
        self.Library_List.insert (END, self.addtitle_box.get())

    def delete_item(self):
        try:
            index = self.Library_List.curselection()[0]
            self.Library_List.delete(index)
        except IndexError:
            pass

    def get_title(self):
        index =  self.Library_List.curselection()[0]
        seltext = self.Library_List.get(index)
        self.SetList_Box.insert(END, "\n" + seltext)

root = Tk()
root.title("SetList Creator")
root.geometry("500x600")

app = Application (root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the width= parameter to size the widgets (same for all widgets but will change with different fonts) http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm  Like your books BTW.

```
import Tkinter as tk

master=tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master, text="default width",
         bg="lightblue").grid()
tk.Label(master, text="width=25", width=25,
         bg="yellow").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(master, text="width=25", width=25, bg="yellow",
        font=("Helvetica", 15)).grid(row=2)
tk.Label(master, text="width=50", width=50,
         bg="orange").grid(row=3)
tk.Button(master, text="Quit", command=master.quit).grid(row=4)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is due tonight, so I got frustrated and switched to using the pack method and frames and that worked well. And I wish I actually WAS him! Haha just a huge fan :)